# After upgrading Clojurescript '1.9.494' getting JSC_PARSE_ERROR

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen, google-closure-compiler, cljsbuild

After upgrading my Clojurescript version `1.8.51` to `1.9.494` I'm getting the following error:

And it says `Successfully compiled` but it does not reflect the new code.

```
ertugrulcetin@Ertugruls-MacBook-Pro ~/I/my-app> lein cljsbuild once min
Compiling ClojureScript...
Compiling "resources/public/js/app.js" from ["src/cljs"]...
Apr 10, 2017 1:43:11 AM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /Users/ertugrulcetin/IdeaProjects/my-app/target/cljsbuild-compiler-0/cljs/core/async.js:1426: ERROR - Parse error. No newline allowed before '=>'
var inst_15586 = async(inst_15585);
                                  ^

    Apr 10, 2017 1:43:11 AM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager printSummary
    WARNING: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
    ERROR: JSC_PARSE_ERROR. Parse error. No newline allowed before '=>' at /Users/ertugrulcetin/IdeaProjects/my-app/target/cljsbuild-compiler-0/cljs/core/async.js line 1426 : 34
```

`Successfully compiled "resources/public/js/app.js" in 11.472 seconds.`

When I switch to `1.8.51` version everything just works fine.

Comment: Have you tried with less new versions of CLJS in the 1.9 series? What version of core.async are you using?

Comment: No, I haven't also I don't use core.async.Is there any 1.9 version that does not have that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug in closure-compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/2336). It's been fixed, but we're just waiting on the next version to be released.

**Edit: It has now been released - version 20170409**